# How to use MAX to sort a limited set of rows by their percentage of the MAX

Tags: sql, sqlite

Lets say I have some data like this

### Fruits

| Fruit | Price | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Orange | 10 | 4 |
| Peach | 20 | 3 |
| Blueberry | 5 | 4 |
| Strawberry | 30 | 1 |
| Apple | 15 | 2 |

What I would like to do is, given a fruit and a price range, find the raking of that fruit within the price range.

For example, lets choose "orange" and "$20":

1. Limit all fruit to less <= $20, so we get (orange, peach, blueberry, apple)
2. Find the max price in that range, so we get 4
3. Calculate the percentage of the max for each so we can see the ranking

| Fruit | Price | Rating | Rating Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Orange | 10 | 4 | 4/4 = 100% |
| Blueberry | 5 | 4 | 4/4 = 100% |
| Peach | 20 | 3 | 3/4 = 75% |
| Apple | 15 | 2 | 2/4 = 50% |

So, in this case we can see that for fruit <= $20 orange is one of the top rated, and is a good buy.

I got as far as:
`select max(rating) from fruits where price <= 20`
But then I don't know how to use that to calculate the rating percentage. I assume sub selects in some form....but I'm drawing a blank.

This also needs to work in Sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `max` window function. Window functions have been supported in SQLite since 3.25.0

```sql
select
  f.*,
  f.Rating || "/" || max(f.Rating) over () || " = " || (f.Rating * 100.0 / max(f.Rating) over ()) || "%" as "rating percentage",
  f.Rating * 100.0 / max(f.Rating) over () as percentage
from fruits f
where f.Price <= 20;
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be:

```
sqlite3 '' <<'EOD'
.headers on
.mode col

create table fruits (fruit,price,rating);
insert into fruits values
    ("orange",    10,4),
    ("peach",     20,3),
    ("blueberry",  5,4),
    ("strawberry",30,1),
    ("apple",     15,2)
;

select
    t.*,
    rating || "/" || m || " = " || (100*rating/m) || "%" as "rating percentage"
from
    ( select * from fruits where price<=20 ) as t,
    ( select max(rating) as m from fruits where price<=20 )
order by rating desc
;
EOD
```

giving:

```
fruit      price  rating  rating percentage
---------  -----  ------  -----------------
orange     10     4       4/4 = 100%
blueberry  5      4       4/4 = 100%
peach      20     3       3/4 = 75%
apple      15     2       2/4 = 50%
```

Comment: personally, I'd `order by rating desc, price asc`  on assumption cheaper for given rating is better value but that may already be part of definition of "rating"

Comment: Why not just use a window function?

Comment: @Charlieface Because I don't know what they are? I don't know how directly it relates to performance, but the `explain` of my sql is half the length of yours.

Comment: @Charlieface okay, have now scanned some tutorials. `over` is useful. thanks!

Comment: @jhnc while this answers my question, as you mention, the window functions are useful. I didn’t know about them either, and now that I do I think I can use them in many other places.